# SQL syntax; check the manual that > corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código que debería cumplir con la siguiente función: Si el alumno esta inscripto a más de 1 escuela, debe borrarse de la tabla de *usuarioesc* junto con la escuela (*id_escuela*) que corresponda.
Si el alumno esta inscripto a solo 1 escuela, entonces debe de borrarse de ambas tablas (*usuarios* y *usuarioesc*).

**Todo esto lo pase a PHP y quedo así:**

```
function eliminarUsuario()
{
    $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    
    $link = conectar();
    $buscaRepetidos = "SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS cuenta FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' GROUP BY id_usuario";

    if ($buscaRepetidos>1){
        
        "SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS cuenta FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' GROUP BY id_usuario";

        "DELETE FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= &id_usuario AND id_escuela='".$id_usuario."'";

        "SELECT cu.id_cursante  FROM cursantes AS cu INNER JOIN cursadas AS cs ON cu.id_cursada=cs.id_cursada WHERE cd.id_escuela= '".$id_usuario."' AND cu.id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."'";

    } elseif ($buscaRepetidos=1) {
        "DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ".$id_usuario;
    }

    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $buscaRepetidos)
                        or die(mysqli_error($link));
    return $resultado;
}
```

Pero salta el siguiente error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '1' at line 1

Otro tema, creo que $buscarRepetidos no tendria que venir aca, sino que tendria que ir el IF pero como lo agrego aca adentro?

```
 $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $buscaRepetidos)
```

Comment: Partir por el que en ningún momento estás guardando las consultas o ejecutandolas... tienes 3 consultas dentro de un if que no estan haciendo nada. Toda la im`plementacion del if esta mal.

Comment: Cuando entras al IF, tienes unos strings con las sentencias SQL. Creería que se las debes asignar a alguna variable para luego ejecutarlas. No lo estás haciendo. Y si concatenas varias consultas, debes asegurarte de que uses un método que soporte esa ejecución batch de consultas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
// Creo que de esta manera te deberia funcionar
// anteriormente parece habia una validacion pero no era util,
// dado que aun no se habia realizado la consulata
$link = conectar();
$buscaRepetidos = "SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS cuenta
                      FROM usuarioesc 
                      WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' GROUP BY id_usuario";
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $buscaRepetidos);

//  aca validas si te devolvio algo lo examinas a ver si es necesario eliminar o no
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
 // aca verificas los datos y los recores como solo deberia ser
// 1 campo puedes omitir el while
  while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
// si cuenta es mayor a es es porque se repite
    if( $row["cuenta"] > 1 ){
// aca deberias eliminar ese registro con el delete daod que retorno mas
// de una coincidencia y se repite, no incluyas si solo hay 1 registor
// porque podria eliminarlo todo
  }
} 
}else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Gracias Carlos, pero salta el siguiente error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)` intente de adaptarlo o modificarlo o pegarlo tal cual pero sigue diciendo este error.

Comment: ya lo edite faltaba un " } ", ahora deberia funcionar

Comment: Funciona... casi, no salta errores pero no borra los usuarios. Tampoco borra nada. Que puede ser?

Comment: Recorda que dentro del if debes agregar la query DELETE * FROM tabla WHERE id= id_repetido